# cake php custom query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have use custom query in cakephp but I dont understand how to run custom join query.
I am using this code

```
$arrayTemp1 = $this->User->query('SELECT DISTINCT
                u.id,u.hunting_association FROM ht_users as u LEFT JOIN 
                `ht_user_animal_prices` as uap ON uap.user_id=u.id  WHERE
                uap.animal_type_id='.$this->request->data['User']['animal'].' ');
```

`User` is the model for `ht_users` and `UserAnimalPrice` is the model for `ht_user_animal_prices`. How to combine the query?

Please help.

Comment: Could all of you please inform yourself about SQL injections!? **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query** | **http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-DboSource.html#_value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom queries and you want the data of UserAnimalPrice model, you just have to put the fields in the query. Something like:

```
$arrayTemp1 = $this->User->query('SELECT DISTINCT u.id,u.hunting_association, uap.* FROM ht_users as u LEFT JOIN  ht_user_animal_prices as uap ON uap.user_id=u.id WHERE uap.animal_type_id='.$this->request->data['User']['animal'].' ');
```

If you prefer not to use custom queries:

```
$fields = array('User.id','User.hunting_association','UserAnimalPrice.*');
$join = array(
   array(
      'table' => 'ht_user_animal_prices',
      'alias' => 'UserAnimalPrice',
      'type'  => 'LEFT',
      'conditions' => array('UserAnimalPrice.user_id = User.id')
   )
);
$conditions = array('UserAnimalPrice.animal_type_id' => $this->request->data['User']['animal']);
$group = array('User.id');

arrayTemp1=arrayTemp1->find('all',array('fields'=>$fields,'joins'=>$join,'conditions'=>$conditions,'group'=>$group));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Correct Query u used .You can also use it in User Model like

```
public function getCustomUsersQuery()
{

$arrayTemp1 = $this->query("
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT u.id,u.hunting_association FROM ht_users as u 
    LEFT JOIN  
    ht_user_animal_prices as uap ON uap.user_id=u.id  
    WHERE 
    uap.animal_type_id='".$this->request->data['User']['animal']."'");
return $arrayTemp1; 
}
```

And call inside Users Controller

```
$result = $this->getCustomUsersQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment on Rizwan answer. If you received the "Call to a member function..." problem, make sure you have the following code

```
public $uses = array('User');
```

this tells that you want to access the user model in that controller. Then you will be allowed to do so.